# HttpURLConnection and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpurlconnection

I need class like `HttpURLConnection` in Java.

I can use `HttpWebRequest` but I need method like that

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(requestURL).openConnection();
for (Property p : property)
    connection.addRequestProperty(p.key, p.value); //HttpWebRequest have that?
connection.connect();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You want the [`WebRequest.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.headers.aspx) property:

```
request.Headers["name"] = value;
```